# Unable to take image using front camera: Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am unable to take pictures using the front camera. My test device definately has both front and back camera/functionality. For some reason pictures are only being taken with back camera. Here is what I have. Note: camera and parameter are globally set.

```
@Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
   {

            camera = Camera.open();
            parameter = camera.getParameters();

            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), parameter);
            parameter.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                Log.e(TAG, "set preview error: ", ignored);
            }
            camera.setParameters(parameter);

        }  
    }
```

In `surfaceChanged()` I start camera preview.

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(isPreview == true)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            isPreview = false;
        }

        if (camera != null)
        {
            try
            {

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
camera.startPreview();
                isPreview = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In `surfaceDestroyed()` I release camera resources

```
@Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
   {
       if (camera != null) {
           camera.stopPreview();

           camera.release();
           camera = null;
           isPreview = false; 
       }

   }
```

Here is the referenced method that returns preview size

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                           Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.size = result;
        return (result);
    }
```

Whenever I want to use the front camera--the front camera is an additional feature, generally the back camera is used--I call `frontCamera()` method. All this method does is set camera-id to 2, which I believe is the flag for `frontCamera()`. I then set parameters with updated parameters and take picture.

```
    private void frontCamera() {

        parameter = camera.getParameters();

            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();

            if (cameraId < 0) {
//no front face camera

            } else {

                parameter.set("camera-id", 2);
                camera.setParameters(parameter);
            }

            camera.takePicture(null,
                    null, myPictureCallback_JPG);

    }
```

My check for front face camera is done in a `findFrontFacingCamera()` method

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        cameraId = -1;
        //search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo cInfo = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cInfo);
            if (cInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Front Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }
```

Final Notes: `numberOfCameras` returns 2, indicating that my test device has two cameras. Also, I am reaching that "Front Camera found" tag which further convinces me that this is not a hardware issue. For whatever reason, this code will only take images with back camera. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.open()`.  Use `.open(cameraID)` and pass it the camera id of the front facing camera.

Comment: I see what you mean here. But here is my question. The general use of this app is with the back camera. The front camera usage (selfie) is just a feature. I guess what I am looking for is a way to update the camera parameters, as opposed to creating a new camera object for front facing camera (the app starts off with back camera, in surfaceCreated). Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Nope.  The only way I know of to get the front camera is to use open and pass it the correct id.  Setting the parameters doesn't change the camera it uses, by the time you have a Camera object you've already chosen which piece of hardware to use.

Comment: Understood. This is enough information for me to get this working I believe. Thanks!